# Restriction functors between Categories O over semi-simple Lie algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, modules, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I have the following question:

Let $\mathfrak{g}:= \mathfrak{gl}(3)$ be the general linear algebra and $\mathfrak{gl}(2) \cong \mathfrak{a} \subset \mathfrak{gl}(3)$ a sub-algebra. Let $\mathcal{O}^{\mathfrak{g}}$ and $\mathcal{O}^{\mathfrak{a}}$ are categories $\mathcal{O}$ of them respectively. Is it true that $\mathcal{O}^{\mathfrak{g}} \subseteq \mathcal{O}^{\mathfrak{a} }$? More precisely, is it true that the restriction  $\text{Res}^{\mathfrak{g}}_{\mathfrak{a}} (V) \in  \mathcal{O}^{\mathfrak{a}} $ if provided that $V\in \mathcal{O}^{\mathfrak{g}}$? Thank you very much!

(Here the definition of the category $\mathcal{O}$ is given as following. Let $\mathcal{s}$ be a finite-dimensional, semi-simple Lie algebra over $\mathbb{C}$. Fix a Bore sub-algebra $\mathfrak{b}$ of $\mathfrak{g}$. Let $\mathfrak{h} \subset \mathfrak{b}$ be a Cartan sub-algebra of $\mathfrak{g}$ with the nilradical $\mathfrak{n}$. Then $W\in \mathcal{O}$ if and only if (1). $W$ is $\mathfrak{h}$-semi-simple. (2). $W$ is locally $\mathfrak{n}$-finite. (3). $W$ is finitely-generated (as $\mathfrak{g}$-module).)

Comment: Do you embed in a specified way? Is the Borel and Cartan of the subalgebra the restrictions of the ones from the larger algebra?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provided the answer to Tobias' question is *yes*, i.e. you take a standard embedding ${\mathfrak g}{\mathfrak l}(2)\subset{\mathfrak g}{\mathfrak l}(3)$, Properties (1) and (2) are preserved, but (3) is in general *not*: First, note that under the assumption of Properties (1) and (2), Property (3) is equivalent to $W$ being finitely generated over the ${\mathfrak n}_-$. Now, consider a Verma module $V$ over ${\mathfrak g}{\mathfrak l}(3)$: As a ${\mathscr U}{\mathfrak n}_-$-module, it is isomorphic to the regular module ${\mathscr U}({\mathfrak n}_-)$, which (by PBW, for example) is free of infinite rank over ${\mathscr U}{\mathfrak n}^{\prime}_-$, the universal enveloping algebra of the lower nilpotent part ${\mathfrak n}^{\prime}_-$ of ${\mathfrak g}{\mathfrak l}(2)$.

Comment: Nice. Do you know if other things go wrong if one chooses the embedding via the adjoint representation (but still choose Borel and Cartan to match).

Comment: You really did me a favor, thank you very much!

Comment: @Khako: You're welcome :)

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: Hm interesting - at the moment I don't see anything that would go wrong: if you pick a basis $\{v_1,...,v_n\}$ of ${\mathfrak g}$ with $v_i\in{\mathfrak g}_{\alpha_i}$ and $\alpha_i\preceq\alpha_j\Rightarrow j\leq i$, then the adjoint representation ${\mathfrak g}\to{\mathfrak g}{\mathfrak l}({\mathfrak g})\cong{\mathfrak g}{\mathfrak l}(n)$ preserves ${\mathfrak h}$, ${\mathfrak n}_+$ and ${\mathfrak n}_-$, so it should preserve properties (1) and (2) again.

Comment: Ok, I reached the same conclusion after asking yesterday (though I didn't work out the details). I just happen to like this embedding because it is an easy example of a "weird" embedding, and gives a good example of an infinite dimensional Lie algebra which is locally isomorphic to some $sl(n)$ but which is not isomorphic to $sl(\infty)$ (one of the uncountably many such).